# How to dynamically fill column values in varying columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
line amount#1   line amount#2 line amount#3  line amount#4 lacheck line amount S
0   13.72                1.92   1.92         NaN            False       5            
1   13.72                1.93   NaN          NaN            False       10           
2   13.72                NaN    NaN          NaN            False       NaN
```

I would like to dynamically fill the first line amount that is NaN with the line amount S.

So desired output would be:

```
line amount#1   line amount#2 line amount#3  line amount#4 lacheck line amount S
0   13.72                1.92   1.92         5              False       5            
1   13.72                1.93   10           NaN            False       10           
2   13.72                NaN    NaN          NaN            False       NaN
```

Anyone who has any idea how to do this?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is select first row by indexing with selecting first `True` by cumulative `sum` for working if no `NaN`s there and set values with chained masks with first value `line amount S`:

```
m = df.loc[0].isna()
m1 = m.cumsum().eq(1)

df.loc[0, m & m1] = df.loc[0, 'line amount S']
print (df)
   line amount#1  line amount#2  line amount#3  line amount#4  lacheck  \
0          13.72           1.92           1.92            5.0    False   
1          13.72           1.93            NaN            NaN    False   
2          13.72            NaN            NaN            NaN    False   

   line amount S  
0            5.0  
1           10.0  
2            NaN
```

EDIT:

For set all rows use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m = df.isna()
m1 = m.cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)
df = df.mask(m & m1, df['line amount S'], axis=0)

print (df)
   line amount#1  line amount#2  line amount#3  line amount#4  lacheck  \
0          13.72           1.92           1.92            5.0    False   
1          13.72           1.93          10.00            NaN    False   
2          13.72            NaN            NaN            NaN    False   

   line amount S  
0            5.0  
1           10.0  
2            NaN
```

Comment: So unfortunately the second row (index =1) does not copy line amount S in line amount #3 (should be 10). What would you do about this jezreal?

Comment: @Max - There is use `m = df.loc[1].isna()` <-changed `0 to 1`, then `m1 = m.cumsum().eq(1)` and last `df.loc[1, m & m1] = df.loc[1, 'line amount S']` <-changed `0 to 1 two times` ?

Comment: Thank you that works well jezreal. Is there a way to do that iteratively for every row? Best, Max

Comment: @Max - So set first `NaN`s by all rows by `line amount S column` ?

Comment: Yes exactly @jezrael

Comment: Is there a way to do that iteratively?

Comment: @Max - I added non loop solution for better performance, can you check?